Try on this/that
While I know 'separable phrasal verbs must be separated when we use personal pronouns - 'it, me, them', how about with 'demonstrative pronouns or indefinite pronouns - 'this, that, some'?
That is, are the expressions (2), (4) below grammatically acceptable?;
(1) Try this on.
(2) Try on this.
(3) Hand some over to me.
(4) Hand over some to me.
For this issue I’m really confused, since I saw an explanation below by a native in an English forum, which no more exists. I would appreciate your response to clarify this issue;

Certain types of phrasal verbs require a nominal object that's semantically independent (i.e., a noun). Pronouns won't work in that environment because they are semantically dependent on an antecedent, which is why D. above and 1. below sound odd to us.

*No. I will wake up him!

'him' is not specific enough, semantically. The reason certain phrasal verbs require a noun has more to do with the semantic make-up of those verbs than it has to do with the structural make up of the grammar (i.e., syntax).
The difference between demonstrative pronouns and personal pronouns (the non-possessive sort, of course) is the former also function as adjectives, which makes it possible for us to pick up the nominal, or specified meaning from the context.
A: This dress doesn't fit me.

Yes, try this (dress) on.
Yes, try on this (dress).

Now, if the pronoun is a demonstrative e.g. 'this' as show below, it sounds perfectly fine:

Yes, try this on.
Yes, try on this.



There was a lot of duplicated text in your original post. I've tried to remove it and reformat. Please check against the original to which I don't have access.

Here's a usage chart where I've multiplied the less common "dress" examples by 30 so you can see the relative preference for putting the preposition before the noun rather than after it with a phrasal verb...

That chart shows monotransitive usages, as with OP's examples (1) and (2). It's perfectly valid to put the preposition before or after the noun - but as you can see, we usually put it before the noun (closer to the verb, where some might think of to try on as a "phrasal verb").
It's syntactically irrelevant whether this stands alone as a "demonstrative pronoun" or functions as a "determiner" before the noun (this dress).

OP's examples (3) and (4) are ditransitive usages, where we can classify to hand over as a phrasal verb. That's a context where learners are taught that if the "indirect object" is a pronoun, it can be inserted within the phrasal verb with no preposition (to me)...

A Hand me some over    (VALID)
B Hand some over to me (VALID)
C Hand some over me (INVALID)
D Hand me some    (VALID)
E Hand some to me (VALID)
F Hand some me (INVALID)

But note that to hand over isn't a very good example of a phrasal verb, since the meaning is largely unaffected by whether over is present or not.
In OP's context it makes no difference whether the particle over is included or not, or whether it's placed before or after the direct object pronoun some. They're all perfectly valid stylistic choices.

Appreciate your explanation with a chart. While I understand 'Try on this dress/Try this dress on' are both valid, are 'Try this on' and 'Try on this' both grammatically acceptable? What I really want to know is the usage of 'this' and 'that' as a demontrative pronoun not as a demontrative adjective in case of phrasal verb.

"It's syntactically irrelevant whether this stands alone as a "demonstrative pronoun" or functions as a "determiner" before the noun (this dress)." Thanks for your additional explanation. Do you mean by this explanation 'Try this on' and 'Try on this' both are grammatically acceptable?

I'd hesitate to say that "Try on this" is grammatically wrong, but to me it feels much less idiomatic than "Try this on".

@Kate Bunting Then, you see the matter of "Try on this/Try this on" as idiomatic rather than grammatic.

@deepcosmos: It's not a matter of grammar as such. Like I said, It's syntactically irrelevant whether this stands alone as a "demonstrative pronoun" or functions as a "determiner" before the noun (this dress). But we're in an unusual situation trying to have opinions about the idiomacy of "standalone this", because in the real world that would never be said unless the referent of this was screamingly obvious (probably in the speaker's hands).

...in fact, if we intend to place heavy stress on a word, we often "instinctively" choose that word at the beginning or end of our utterance. In contexts like sarcastic / intimidating "How do you like them apples?" / What do you think of this?, it's potentially far more intense if you can put all the stress on the very last thing you say. So arguably "Why don't you try on this?" might be more appropriate when "this" is some totally outlandish possibility (introduced with a theatrical flourish, perhaps). Don't overthink it though - you're not learning grammar here.
